# Too many values to unpack or 0 values to unpack

Tags: python, list, unicode, ipython

I have this code and I am trying to use the list splits
but either I get Too many values to unpack or need more than 0 values to unpack

```
def edits1(word):
    splits  = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]

    temp1 = []
    for i in splits:
        temp = list(i)
        for j in range(0,len(temp)):
            temp1.append(temp[j])

    splits = temp1

    for s in splits:
        print s
    #here 
    deletes    = [a + b[1:] for a, b in splits if b]

    return set(deletes)
```

Comment: Your `splits` list ends up being a list of strings, some of which are only one character. If you want to write `for a,b in splits`, each element of `splits` needs to have two things in it.

Comment: You need to skip the first and last item in `splits`, as it ends up containing empty entries. With the word `test`, it looks like `[('', 'test'), ('t', 'est'), ('te', 'st'), ('tes', 't'), ('test', '')]`. Also, check out ipythons `%debug` function. It is quite awesome for debugging stuff like this!